# ggplot create grouped boxplots by filtering data in one column

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to create grouped boxplots by filtering data in one column by years < 1993 and years > 1993

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

months <- c(7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8)
years <- c(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995)
values <- c(12.1,11.5,12.0,12.4,12.2,11.8,11.4,12.2,11.8,12.0)

dt <- data.table(month=months,year=years,value=values)

aug_dt_lessthan1993 <- dt %>% 
  filter(month==8,year<1993)

aug_dt_greaterthan1993 <- dt %>% 
  filter(month==8,year>1993)

p <- ggplot(aug_dt_lessthan1993, aes(x=1,y=value,fill=))
```

Can I use fill for this?

Is there an easy way keep all the data in one data.table? And create grouped boxplots by filtering the years variable?

Comment: Consider adding the package dependencies to the beginning of your code snippet to make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the year grouped by a condition?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

months <- c(7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8)
years <- c(1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995)
values <- c(12.1,11.5,12.0,12.4,12.2,11.8,11.4,12.2,11.8,12.0)

dt <- data.table(month=months,year=years,value=values)

MONTH=8
YEAR=1993

dt %>% 
  # Apply filter for month
  filter(
    month == MONTH
  ) %>% 
  # Tag year based on your condition
  mutate(year_group = ifelse(year > YEAR, "After 1993", "Before 1993")) %>% 
  # Create plot
  ggplot(aes(y=value, x=1, fill=year_group)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

This code produces the following plot:
[image: Plot]

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.